# How can I open gliffy diagrams by double clicking?

Tags: google-chrome, default-programs, mime-type

I installed a program "Gliffy" as a Google Chrome app.  It saves it's diagrams as *.gliffy files.  I'm wondering if I could set things up so that I can double click on this *.gliffy file and it opens up in the Gliffy editor.

EDIT:  I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

EDIT: First step seems to be adding a new mime type for *.gliffy files - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_Applications#Custom_file_associations

Comment: Won't answer your question (which is fairly old by the way), but just to add some information, double-clicking in Windows Explorer does not work in MS Windows also.